# Missing output from pyspark's profiler

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, profiling, pyspark

I'm trying to profile a pyspark job submitted to my cluster. This pyspark PR (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2556) indicates `sc.dump_profiles(path)` is the command. I've tried dumping the profile output to hadoop `hdfs:///user/username/filename`, and locally `file:///home/username/filename`, and `/home/username/filename`. The job completes but the profile never appears.

The code is based on this SO question ([How to profile pyspark jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253203/how-to-profile-pyspark-jobs)), and sc.show_profiles() *does* work in interactive mode when including `--conf spark.python.profile=true`.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("profile")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100)).map(str)
    rdd.count()

    sc.show_profiles()
    sc.dump_profiles("hdfs:///user/username/python_profiled")
```

I submit the job like this `/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --verbose --conf spark.python.profile=true --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue production --num-executors 4 test_profile.py`

Any pointers on how to format `path` to get the profile output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three different problems:

- `dump_profiles` uses standard Python writers so you'll need POSIX compliant file system to use it here. HDFS won't do unless mounted using FUSE.
- Python file utilities expect path to file not URI. Code you've shown should throw an exception.
- When submitting your code in the cluster mode `dump_profiles` will use a path local to the driver node, which will be an arbitrary node on your cluster.

If you don't have access to POSIX compliant DFS you could read the dump back in your application and push it to HDFS using one of the available Python clients or push it to something like S3 bucket.

A bit more cumbersome solutions is to distribute it using `SparkFiles` (`SparkContext.addFile`), read it with `texFile` and write.